# return a boolean value from request to use it outside the request response promise

Tags: typescript, cypress

I have the following method

```
function testSkipping(channel='US', test:any) : boolean{
cy.log(test) // will print SkipPaymentTests

    cy.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: Cypress.env('EndPoint') + 'features',
        headers: {
            'Channel': `${channel}`,
            'Subscription-Key': Cypress.env('sKey'),
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
            if (response?.status === 200) {
                expect(response.body.feature).to.exist;
            cy.log(response.body.featureFlags.test)

                if (response.body.feature[`${test}`]) {
                    return true /// I need to return this value
                } else 
                {
                  return false // I need to return this value
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

this code does not return the proper value stored in the backend

the response of the call is

```
{
"SkipPaymentTests":true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think return will give you proper value here. You can try to create global variable and set as below :

```
var sucessValue = false;
function testSkipping(channel='US', test:any) : boolean{
cy.log(test) // will print SkipPaymentTests

    cy.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: Cypress.env('EndPoint') + 'features',
        headers: {
            'Channel': `${channel}`,
            'Subscription-Key': Cypress.env('sKey'),
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
            if (response?.status === 200) {
                expect(response.body.feature).to.exist;
            cy.log(response.body.featureFlags.test)

                if (response.body.feature[`${test}`]) {
                    sucessValue = true; /// I need to return this value
                } else 
                {
                  sucessValue = false; // I need to return this value
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```